# How to change progressBar in cuba into a circular

Tags: cuba-platform, cuba

am using cuba studio v7.2 and i want to change the progressBar to circular,

am stuck because i dont know which file to change and after following different

documents, the file am finding they are read-only files, I cannot change

anything. the online material is about setting the indeterminate to true

which is a read-only java file

any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to add the "Progress Bar" component to your screen and then set a style to it as described [in the documentation](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-7.2/gui_ProgressBar.html) and in the [example](https://demo10.cuba-platform.com/sampler/#main/6/sample?id=indeterminate-progressbar).

If you want to change the system-wide progress bar on the top of the application window, you need to create your own custom style for this. There is no built-in style for the system-wide progress bar, so you'll need to deal with absolute positioning, calculate z-index, etc. There is no example of this for now.